# What is a regular expression to match square brackets and the content between square brackets?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a expression like `[2180]:`. I want to match everything including square brackets and colon mark.

I tried using `/\[/[/d+]/\]/:` but it seems it doesn't work perfectly.

Let us go for another example: `vpnagent[2284]:`.

What would be the regular expression for the above string?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend heading to [Rubular](http://rubular.com) and get familiar with Regular expression patterns. The patterns you seek are not exclusive to Ruby, they're very general for Perl-compatible regex. Rubular will help you *SEE* the effect of changes you make to your patterns. See http://rubular.com/r/9aBRPqgjvH for an example.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be confusing slashes (used to delimit a regex) and backslashes (used to escape regex metacharacters or for special regex shorthand escape sequences):

```
/\[\d+\]:/
```

is what you need.